# Why are AbstractQueue and AbstractList disjointed?

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections

During my C learning days, when I had implemented a `Queue`, I implemented them on top of a `LinkedList`. So essentially I had two pointers (front and rear) for the `Queue` operations on top of `LinkedList`, or better one front pointer on top of a `CircularLinkedList`.

I am learning the Java `Collections Framework`, and I observe that the design has completely disjointed the `List` and `Queue` interfaces, and the implementations branches out in following fashion -

[image]

I think `AbstractQueue` should have been subclassed somewhere inside `AbstractList`. Maybe not inside `ArrayList`, because I do not want random access to elements, but maybe inside  `AbstractSequentialList`, hmm? (I realize, I could be completely wrong here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like something done for implementation flexibility: a queue doesn't have to be implemented as a list (in particular a priority-queue is almost certainly a heap underneath, which is a much more random-access structure than a list can offer).

Answer (score 2):

I think the interfaces should be disjoint, but there is a link in the method of implementation as you have identified. A list and a queue are conceptually different to the consumer when treated as a black box, even if there is a link between how you might implement them using a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) come into play here? An AbstractQueue *IS NOT* an AbstractList, so it shouldn't inherit from it. It's implementation may use one, however, but by composition not inheritance.